# concatenate cells (using variables in a loop) and keep the fill colour in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that looks like:

[image]

So I have those matrixes in the sheet (lets say this is Sheet1). I have a lot of similar sheets.
I need to arrive at a result in another sheet, result that look like that:

```
4500
4501
4502
4503
4504
4505
4506
4507
4508
4509
4510
4511
.
.
.
4599
```

So I need to concatenate the cells in order to come at the above results.
In my example, lets say that the number "45" is on the merged cells A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1.
In that matrix, with the header "45":

- "00" will be on A2,
- "01" will be on B2 and so on.

The concatenate it's simple. (or not...)
I made a new sheet (Sheet2), made a command button and put this code:

```
Range("A1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
Range("A2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
and so on, which works, but i would like something with variables...
```

But i am new to VBA and a don't quite understand how i can do this in order to not write hundreds of lines of code...

The other (big) problem is that i need to keep the colour of the last cell which participates at the concatenation.
Examples:
`For "4500" the colour in the results sheet must be blue.`
`For "4555" the colour in the results sheet must be white.`
`For "4580" the colour in the results sheet must be yellow.`
So i need to keep the exact index colour.

I need to do those concatenations and to keep the colour for every matrix.
I can't figure out how to maintain the colour.. I used something with Interior.ColorIndex but i put this manually after the concatenation.. which doesn't work for my case, because this excel file is very big.

I think I need to make a loop and to concatenate and in the same time keep the colour.

I'm newbie in VBA but i find this very interesting. Any help is very appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You know you need to make a loop - so try something out, then post back here if you run into specific problems.  The fill color of a cell can be accessed using `cell.Interior.Color` and there are plenty of examples here of how to loop over a range.

Comment: @TimWilliams, Thanks! I can't find here how to loop in those matrixes. And for the cell.Interior.Color, it is working just if I set to it an index. So I can't actually take the color that I already have, I have to search for the index of that color and manually set it.

Answer (score 0):

A rough outline for looping over a block:

```vb
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, cDest As Range, hdr
    
    Set cDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("a2")
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:K11")
    hdr = rng.Cells(1).Offset(-1, 0).Value 'header
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        With cDest
            .Value = hdr & c.Text
            .Interior.Color = c.Interior.Color
        End With
        Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0)
    Next c
```